# How to parse path dynamically in gulp.src.options.base

Tags: javascript, gulp, main-bower-files

I'm trying to write gulp-based application using main-bower-files. I want to copy all my and vendor assets files to **%build_dir%/assets** folder, but fonts files should be copied in **%build_dir%/assets/fonts**. Without vendor files it can be done easy via ***gulp.src.options.base*** option. But i can't understand how to do it with vendor files. Now i have

```
gulp.task('assets', ['less'], function() {
    return gulp.src('src/less/fonts/*', {base: 'src/less'})
        .pipe(addSrc('src/assets/**.*'))
        .pipe(addSrc(mainBowerFiles(/.*woff|woff2|otf|ttf/, {includeDev: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir + '/assets'));
});
```

But it copies vendor fonts to **%build_dir%/assets**.
So, ideal case is to write **base** as regexp that parses path to vendor fonts and take all path before **/fonts**. How to do it?

Vendor folder has next structure:

```
/bower_components
   /lib1
      /fonts
         font1.woff
   /lib2
      /fonts
         font2.otf
   /lib3
      /fonts
         font3.ttf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, ideal case is to write base as regexp that parses path to vendor fonts and take all path before /fonts. How to do it?

Not possible. The `base` option doesn't support regexes. Only strings.

You don't need the `base` option anyway. Just create two streams each with their own `gulp.dest()`. Then merge those streams using [`merge-stream`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-stream):

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('assets', ['less'], function() {
  return merge(
    gulp.src(['src/less/fonts/*'].concat(mainBowerFiles(/.*woff|woff2|otf|ttf/, {includeDev: true})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir + '/assets/fonts')),
    gulp.src('src/assets/**.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(buildDir + '/assets')));
});
```

This also means you don't need `gulp-add-src` anymore.